# Upgrade MVC 5 web solution from .net framework 4.5 to 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 solution that contains 6 projects. These projects are targeted against the .net framework version 4.5. I want to update this so they target version 4.6.

I'm looking for a definitive list of steps I need to carry out to achieve this as there seems to be various opinions about what needs doing.

As well as changing the projects to target 4.6 in the application section of each projects properties and updating nuget packages to their latest version, is there anything else I need to do?

Regards
Macca

Comment: See the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836046/visual-studio-2013-and-net-4-6

Answer (score 0):

Also check your nuget packages to see are they compliant with new .net version or not. In some cases you need to update them. Also check your other third party references or tools to see are they compatible or not.